# Multiple screen manipulation using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiple-monitors

I would like some help in figuring out how exactly multiple screens work.
Here is my code so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

def create_window():
    window1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
def Create_window2():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
def quit():
    global root
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()

login = tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=Create_window2)
register = tk.Button(root, text="Register", command=create_window)
Exit = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=quit)
login.pack()
register.pack()
Exit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So after clicking the button to login or register, it will create a separate screen. I would like to know how exactly to edit that screen. For example, how would I put in a label or a 'quit' button on the second screen?

Comment: What does "Enthought Canopy" refer to?

Comment: Enthought Canopy is simply is a python enviornment made easier to handle.

Comment: To add a label to the window: `tk.Label(window1, ...)`.

Comment: the "screen" here. what are they referring to? a monitor or a Tkinter window?